Identify a movie about boys imprisoned after injured/killed a men with an hot dog stand
About 10 years ago I watched a movie on TV about a group of boys that were imprisoned after they pushed a hot dog stand down some stairs, resulting in either the injury or death of a man. It took place in the States.
In the prison/institution they encountered highly abusive prison guards. For example, the inmates played an important football game against the guards.  The inmates won due to a very athletic black lad. After the game he was heavily beat up by the guards as pay back. One of the protagonists stated: "Even his mother/parents couldn't recognize him."
Several years later one protagonist met one of his former guards in a restaurant or bar, recognizes and shoots him.
I have no idea what happens after this.
I think this movie is from the 80s to late 90s.  
Does anybody recognizes this movie and know its title?

was it in English?  is it American?  did you watch it on tv or in theatre?

Sleepers

After a prank goes disastrously wrong, a group of boys are sent to a
  detention center where they are brutalized; over 10 years later, they
  get their chance for revenge.

Wikipedia:

In the summer of 1967, their lives take a turn when they accidentally almost kill a man after pulling a prank on a hot dog
  vendor. As punishment, the boys are sentenced to the Wilkinson Home
  for Boys in Upstate New York; Tommy, Michael and John sentenced to
  12-18 months, while Shakes is given 6-12 months. There, the boys are
  systematically abused and raped by guards Sean Nokes, Henry Addison,
  Ralph Ferguson, and Adam Styler. The horrifying abuse changes the boys
  and their friendship forever.

Trailer:



In the trailer above you can see the accident with the hot dog vendor. 

Awesome! Ah it was a hot dog stand not ice cream ^^
